# JMeter CSV Data Set is corrupting Japanese strings stored as proper UTF-8, I get Question Marks instead

Tags: encoding, csv, utf-8, jmeter

I read in search terms from a simple text file to send to a search engine.
It works fine in English, but gives me ???? for any Japanese text.
Text with mixed English and Japanese does show the English text, so I know it's reading it.

What I'm seeing:

- Input text:
     Snow Leopard をインストールする場合、新しい
- Turns into:
     Snow Leopard ???????????????

This is in my POST field of an HTTP.
If I set JMeter to encode the data, it just puts in the percent sequence for question marks.

About the Data:

- The CSV file is very simple in
  structure.
- There's only one field / one column,
  which I name TERM, and later use as
  ${TERM}
- I don't really need full CSV because it's only one string per line.
- There's no commas or quotes.
- It's UTF-8 and when I run the Unix "file" command on the file, it says UTF-8 text.
- I've also verified UTF-8 in command line and graphical mode on two machines.

Interesting note:
An interesting coincidence that I noticed: if there are 15 Japanese characters then I get 15 question marks, so at some point it's being seen as full characters and not just bytes.

JMeter CSV Dataset Config:

- Filename: japanese-searches.csv
- File encoding: UTF-8 (also tried without)
- Variable names: TERM
- Delimiter: ,
- Allow Quoted Data: False (I also tried True, different, but still wrong)
- Recycle at EOF: True
- Stop at EOF: False
- Staring mode: All threads

A few things I've tried:
 - Tried Allow quoted Data.  It changed to other strange characters.
 - Added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 - Tried encoding the POST stage, but it just turned into a bunch of %nn for question marks

And I'm not sure how "debug" just after the each line of the CSV is read in.  I *think* it's corrupted right away, but I'm not sure.

If it's only mangled when I reference it, then instead of ${TERM} perhaps there's some other "to bytes" function call.  I'll start checking into that.  I haven't done anything with the JMeter functions yet.

Edited Dec 24:

Tweaks:

- Changed formatting and added bullet
  points for more clarity.
- Clarified that the file is UTF-8, and have verified that.

A new theory:

- Is it possible that the Japanese characters are making it through, and the issue is that EVERY SINGLE place that shows them maps them to a "?" at DISPLAY TIME only.  So even though I've checked in a bunch of places, they all have a display issue just in the UI?
- Is there a way in JMeter to see the numeric value of a character or string?  Actually, to tell JMeter to display the list of Unicode code points?
- I'll look at my last log files... although I suppose even the server logs could mis-mapped the characters.
- Also, perhaps when doing variable expansion inside of the text field that I POST, where I reference the ${TERM}, maybe at *that* point it also maps to question marks, but that the corruption happens at that later point.  If that happened, AND it was mis-displayed in the UI, then it might lead to a false conclusion.
- What I'd really like to do is pause JMeter after the first CSV record, just after that line is loaded, and look at it with a "data scope" or byte editor or something.  Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I don't think this is very clear. You say you're reading from a text file but don't mention what encoding it is in, or how it is read (eg Java code) and if so, what code it's using. I think you're more likely to get a response if you don't rely on anyone knowing exactly how JMeter works.

Comment: I did mention UTF-8, and I verified it.  I'll edit the formatting, maybe more bullet points.  Also have a bit more info.

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue.  This article may help: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t169159-strangeness-with-japanese-xml-java.html  else I would post to the nabble forum: http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-User-f512775.html

Comment: Did you try quoted text AND putting the japanese characters in your CSV in quotes?  After doing research, simply setting the encoding to "UTC-8" should work.

Comment: Hi BlackGaff, thanks for the comments.  I didn't have quotation marks in the file because there's only one field per line, and no commas, but I may try that. I searched on the JMeter forum, no smoking gun yet. I'll look at the UTC-8.  At the moment I've decided to put up a tiny web server that just outputs the hex/octal codes of what it is being sent, and I'll have JMeter submit to that.  I want to prove, one way or the other, whether JMeter is really sending question marks, OR just every place in the UI where it tries to display a Japanese character, it mis-maps it ON SCREEN.

Comment: Hi BlackGaff.  I tried your suggested encoding "UTC-8" instead of UTF-8 but then no records came in and I got "${TERM} instead. I'm pretty sure UTC-8 is a timezone, and if you meant UTF-8, that's what I've been doing.  I also tried putting quotes around the input fields, no change.  And adding more debug statements on the server side, it's getting just literal question marks "?", not Unicode. I've seen CJK text in the server logs before, so the failure is in JMeter.

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue, there was another place the UTF-8 had to be specified.

In the HTTP Request, to the right of the Method, you have to also set Content Encoding to UTF-8

Yes, in hindsight, this seems obvious, but there were a number of reasons I didn't think this was needed.  Some of my incorrect assumptions might be helpful for others who are debugging, so here goes - I would have thought that:

1: Once text has made it into Java as Unicode, it stays as Unicode, and goes in and out by UTF-8.  Obviously not in this case.

2: I sort of thought HTTP defaulted to UTF-8 unless you say otherwise, but maybe I'm just used to XML, but probably not a good practice to assume that, and maybe HTTP defaults to ISO-Latin1 or something, or even if there's a spec, maybe folks don't follow it.

3: And if I don't specific it, I'd think the "do no harm" approach would be to pass the characters on, and let the receiver on the other end deal with it.  Wrong again!

(OK, so points 1, 2 and 3 overlap a bit)

4: Even though my HTTP Request POST, I did still try the Encode checkbox. I certainly thought that would have encoded it, but all I got was the repeating % hex for question marks, so seemed to me that the data was already corrupted at that point.  Wrong again.  I suspect WITHIN the HTTP phase, there's TWO character transitions, first from Unicode to whatever encoding it thinks you have, and THEN a second encoding into the %signs, and my data was mis-encoded at the first step.

5: And I would have thought JMeter would say something or warn, but from my reading, apparently it's not helpful in that respect.  You can do logging or whatever.

And the "?" is Java's way of reporting a problem BY default, this started in the Java 1.4x timeframe.  In my Java code I prefer to set encoding errors to report as an exception, but again, not the default, and not what JMeter does.

So I learned my lesson.

The HINT that the Unicode was at least starting out OK was that the number of question marks equaled the number of Japanese characters, instead of having 2 or 3 times as many question marks.  If the length of "???" matches your Japanese (or Chinese) string, then Java DID see actual Unicode characters at some point along the journey.  Whereas if you see 3 times as many ?'s as input text, then Java always saw them as bytes or ints or whatever, and NEVER as valid codepoints.

Comment: As of Java 1.4x you can tell Java to THROW EXCEPTIONS when it hits encoding errors, instead of just silently replacing them with question marks. This may be too strict for production applications, but for debugging and TESTING I find it helpful. The trick is the Charset object that you use: Charset charset Charset.forName( charsetName );
CharsetDecoder dec = charset.newDecoder();
dec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
Then be prepared to handle exceptions of java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException or subclasses: MalformedInputException and UnmappableCharacterException
Very strict!

Comment: AND I had also done -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 so I thought Java would default to that if it was ever unsure.  But this was also incorrect, at least for JMeter's HTTP pipeline stage.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this topic when searching for solution to use parameters from csv file that contained some columns written in Hebrew.

1. I used Excel 2007 to create a 1000 lines data for user registrations. The first and the last names had to be in Hebrew.
   I exported the file to "Unicode text" file. It became tab delimited.
   "Unicode Text" saves in UTF-16 LE (Little Endian), not in UTF-8. That is important.
2. I opened the result in Notepad++. I could see the Hebrew letters properly. The Notepad++ has the "Encoding" menu item, where you can check the encoding or change it. So I changed the Little Endian to UTF-8.
   Then I replaced tabs with commas (just selected the tab and pasted it into the Find box.
3. The parameters were substituted ok, but after running the script I saw the following:
   In the "View Results Tree" listener I opened the "Result" tab of the "Http Request".
   The parameters were substituted, but the HTTP view tab (on the bottom) of the Request showed me some gibberish.
   But when I looked at the Raw view, I saw that the request parameters actually contained strings like %D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94 that when taken in pairs (%D7 %A9) corersponded properly to Hebrew letters.

To my mind, the JMeter has a bug and can not properly display the unicode chars. But it sends (POSTs) them out ok.

Hope I am right and hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use "SHIFT-JIS" in Content encoding (it's nearby Method selection). Then you should uncheck "Encode?" for parameter that included Japanese.

Hope it works you.